# Cannot resolve symbol ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I wish to store data in order to handle change in screen orientation which leads to calling of onCreate method everytime orientation changes. Hence, as per Android documentation, it is suggested to use 'ViewModel' but I am getting the error that ViewModel cannot be resolved.

> [Cannot use android:configChanges as I have a different landscape and portrait views]

Here is the code:

```
public static class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private String mUserId;
    private String mProductId;
}
```

Comment: You **obviously** have to import any class you want to use

Comment: Why viewmodel is a static class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you need to implements this two line in build gradle:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to work with Android Studio 2.3. I tried numerous Gradle changes etc. but no luck. I upgraded to the new Studio 3.2.1 and it works fine. Not sure what Studio version you are using.
I still needed to add the implementation line for lifecycle:extensions to the build.gradle file for the module (not the project one):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1' <== added
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Without the added implementation line the "ViewModelProviders" could not be found.